# my button won't work, why?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, button, piezo

I have been trying to get the button to work properly for over a day, but it just won't, can you help me.

The lcd display is for another part of this project, not important at the moment, but I can't take it away.

Also, the piezo plays the sound within else{}.

```
const int buttonPin = A0;

int buttonState = 0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {


  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    tone(8, 400);
  }else{
    tone(8, 300);
    delay(375);
    tone(8, 200);
    delay(375);
    tone(8, 100);
    delay(750);
    tone(8, 400);
    delay(250);
    noTone(8);
    delay(5000);
  }


}
```

[image: Arduino circuit]

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to actually *read* the button state from the button...

Comment: @Majenko you mean this? buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

Comment: buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

Comment: Yes. Without that how can your program know what the button is doing?

Comment: i have that in the code i'm using, I forgot to copy it to this code. @Majenko

Comment: I didn't want to add all the code, because half of it are some custom characters i have made. @Majenko

Comment: So try your posted code for yourself and see if it does what it should do. Don't try and second guess yourself - the first step of debugging something is to write a program that tests that one thing and then see what the results are.

Comment: @Majenko Well, i have a program that sees if my code has any problems, I already tried my posted code for myself and it doesn't do what it should do.

Comment: Did you include the digitalRead in the program you tested?

Comment: @Majenko Yes i did.

Comment: @Majenko do you want me to post all the code i have, including the custom characters for the lcd?

Comment: No. With your test code did you hold in the button and wait the 7 or so seconds before it came time to test it again? Or did you just tap it hoping that all those delays would not matter?

Comment: @Majenko Okay, so with the 7 second delay it works, is there a way to make it work when i just tap it?

Comment: Define "work". At the moment it does exactly what you have programmed it to. If you want it to do something else you will have to program it to do something else. What do you *want* it to do?

Comment: @Majenko Well eventually I want to make a side-scrolling game, where you have to jump over obstacles, the sounds will be on a different place, except that one if you press the button

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn the art of writing non-blocking code. The use of `delay()` should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @Majenko Got it, but can i use those delays for a death sound.

Comment: You can only use delay at a time when you are not wanting to do anything else at all. If all you are doing is playing the tune then sure, use delays. But never if you are doing anything else, like reading a button.

Comment: @Majenko Okay, thank you for taking the time to help me